# Avoid object allocations warning appears when creating multi-layer drawing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable

After creating a digram using Java, 3 areas get highlighted and return a warning for some reason. I'm not sure why this is appearing. What can be done to get rid of this warning?

> Avoid object allocations during draw/layout operations (preallocate and reuse instead)

[image]
[image]

```
public class Diagram extends View {
    private int measuredWidth, measuredHeight;
    private Paint mBackgroundPaint, mYellowLinePaint, mWhiteLinePaint;
    private RectF mBackgroundRect, mYellowLineRectF, mWhiteLineRectF;


    public Diagram(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public Diagram(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public Diagram(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {

        mBackgroundPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mBackgroundPaint.setColor(0xFF3C3C3C);
        mBackgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        mYellowLinePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mYellowLinePaint.setColor(0xFFFFFF00);
        mYellowLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        mWhiteLinePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mWhiteLinePaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        mWhiteLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        measuredHeight = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        measuredWidth = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);

        mBackgroundRect = new RectF(0, 0, measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
        mYellowLineRectF = new RectF(0, 0.2f * measuredHeight, measuredWidth, 0.3f * measuredHeight);
        mWhiteLineRectF = new RectF(0, 0.0f * measuredHeight, measuredWidth, 0.1f * measuredHeight);

        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (measuredHeight == 0 || measuredWidth == 0)
            return;

        canvas.drawRect(mBackgroundRect, mBackgroundPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mYellowLineRectF, mYellowLinePaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mWhiteLineRectF, mWhiteLinePaint);
    }
}
```

**Updated code**

```
public class Diagram extends View {
    private int measuredWidth, measuredHeight;
    private Paint mBackgroundPaint, mYellowLinePaint, mWhiteLinePaint;

    private final RectF mBackgroundRect = new RectF();
    private final RectF mYellowLineRectF = new RectF();
    private final RectF mWhiteLineRectF = new RectF();

    public Diagram(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public Diagram(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public Diagram(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {

        mBackgroundPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mBackgroundPaint.setColor(0xFF3C3C3C);
        mBackgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        mYellowLinePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mYellowLinePaint.setColor(0xFFFFFF00);
        mYellowLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        mWhiteLinePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mWhiteLinePaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        mWhiteLinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        measuredHeight = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        measuredWidth = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);

        mBackgroundRect.set(0, 0, measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
        mYellowLineRectF.set(0, 0.2f * measuredHeight, measuredWidth, 0.3f * measuredHeight);
        mWhiteLineRectF.set(0, 0.0f * measuredHeight, measuredWidth, 0.1f * measuredHeight);

        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (measuredHeight == 0 || measuredWidth == 0)
            return;

        canvas.drawRect(mBackgroundRect, mBackgroundPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mYellowLineRectF, mYellowLinePaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mWhiteLineRectF, mWhiteLinePaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have you included your code as a screenshot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your 3 `RectF` instances once in the class constructor or field initializer instead, then use `RectF.set()` in `onMeasure()`.

```
public class Diagram extends View {
    private final RectF mBackgroundRect = new RectF();
    private final RectF mYellowLineRectF = new RectF();
    private final RectF mWhiteLineRectF = new RectF();

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        measuredHeight = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        measuredWidth = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);

        mBackgroundRect.set(0, 0, measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
        mYellowLineRectF.set(0, 0.2f * measuredHeight, measuredWidth, 0.3f * measuredHeight);
        mWhiteLineRectF.set(0, 0.0f * measuredHeight, measuredWidth, 0.1f * measuredHeight);

        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't understand how to create them once when they are all different colours.

Comment: Still unsure of how to do this as I've never used this method before. Do the RectF instances in onMeasure need to moved?

Comment: Thanks. Based on that my updated code is above under **Updated code** hence according to it, are there any parts that should be removed?

Comment: No I don't think so, but you should use the actual view size that you can retrieve in onSizeChanged() rather than the desired one you currently get from onMeasure() instead. But that would be another question.

Comment: OK cool. Thanks for your help. Your answer has been accepted.